# NetworkOnMainThreadException even after using asynctask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have found few questions in stackOverflow related to this topic but was unable to find a suitable answer.In my app,I intend to do network communications via separate thread.So I used asynctask.But even after using asynctask I found the networkOnMainThreadException.Here is my code :

```
private static final String CATEGORY_ALL_FETCHING_URL = "http://qpon.es/coupon/index.php/welcome/categories/all";
private static final String CATEGORY_IMAGE_URL = "http://qpon.es/images/coupons/";
private static final String TAG_CATEGORY_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_CATEGORY_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_CATEGORY_IMAGE = "img";
private static final String TAG_CATEGORY_CREATE_DATE = "created";
private static final String CATEGORY_INTENT = "category";

private ProgressDialog downloadingStatusIndicator = null;
private ArrayList<Category> categoryList = null;
private CustomCategoryAdapter customAdapter = null;

private class CateoryListDataGenerator extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        downloadingStatusIndicator = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        downloadingStatusIndicator.setTitle(R.string.categoryDownloadTitle);
        downloadingStatusIndicator.setMessage("Retrieving Categories...");
        downloadingStatusIndicator.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String response = "";
        try {

            Log.d("BACK THREAD STARTS", "YES");
            categoryList = new ArrayList<Category>();
            response = JSONParser
                    .getRemoteResponse(CATEGORY_ALL_FETCHING_URL);

            // Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.d("BACKGROUD", e.getMessage());
        }

        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {

        JSONArray categoriesJSON = null;
        try {
            categoriesJSON = new JSONArray(response);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < categoriesJSON.length(); i++) {

            Log.d("LOOP BEGINS", "YES");
            Category eachCategory = new Category();

            JSONObject eachCategoryJSON = null;
            try {
                eachCategoryJSON = categoriesJSON.getJSONObject(i);
                eachCategory.setCategoryName(eachCategoryJSON
                        .getString(TAG_CATEGORY_NAME));
                eachCategory.setCategoryCreateDate(eachCategoryJSON
                        .getString(TAG_CATEGORY_CREATE_DATE));
                eachCategory.setCategoryImagePath(CATEGORY_IMAGE_URL
                        + eachCategoryJSON.getString(TAG_CATEGORY_IMAGE));
                eachCategory.setCategoryID(eachCategoryJSON
                        .getInt(TAG_CATEGORY_ID));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            categoryList.add(eachCategory);
            Log.d("CATEGORY INSERTED", categoryList.toString());
        }

        Log.d("CATEGORY LIST", categoryList.toString());

        if (categoryList != null || categoryList.size() > 0) {
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            for (int i = 0; i < categoryList.size(); i++) {
                customAdapter.add(categoryList.get(i));

            }

            downloadingStatusIndicator.dismiss();
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

In JSONParder's setRemoteRenponse() method :

```
boolean isURLFetched = false;

    while(!isURLFetched){

        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
            content = execute.getEntity().getContent();
            isURLFetched = true;

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

            Log.d("HERE", "ONE");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            Log.d("HERE", "TWO");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            Log.d("HERE", "THREE");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {

        BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                content));
        String s = "";
        while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            response += s;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    return response;
```

Lastly the asynctask class object is created & executed in the fragment's onActivityCreated() method :

```
CateoryListDataGenerator dataGenerator = new CateoryListDataGenerator();
dataGenerator.execute(new String[] { CATEGORY_ALL_FETCHING_URL });
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I have included INTERNET permission too.For now,I have changed the thread policy to work this app on android 3.0 or higher but this is no solution.

Here is the logcat message:

```
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at     android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:341)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at com.example.couponapp.adapters.CustomCategoryAdapter.getScaledBitmapFromFile(CustomCategoryAdapter.java:83)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at com.example.couponapp.adapters.CustomCategoryAdapter.getView(CustomCategoryAdapter.java:58)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:733)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1608)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2102)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4362)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1866)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1687)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: where do you call setRemoteRenponse()?

Comment: @Raghunandan probably He meant getRemoteRenponse() ?

Comment: @blackbelt agreed. he is trying to make a network related operation      HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet); in setRemoteRenponse() so maybe the method is invoked on the ui thread

Comment: @Raghunandan HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); can run on the UI THread. Is the execute method that has to run on a different thread

Comment: @Raghunandan , sorry for my spelling mistake...@blackbelt was right..it will be getRemoteRenponse().But I am invoking execute() method at doInBackground().Isn't it in separate thread?

Comment: @A.T.M.SALEH post logcat details of the exception

Comment: @A.T.M.SALEH whats in line 83 in CustomCategoryAdapter.java and line no 58

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem is not here. From the logs, from within the adapter,

```
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at com.example.couponapp.adapters.CustomCategoryAdapter.getScaledBitmapFromFile(CustomCategoryAdapter.java:83)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at com.example.couponapp.adapters.CustomCategoryAdapter.getView(CustomCategoryAdapter.java:58)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2267)
```

You can see that the getView() method is trying to load an image, which in turn is making a network request to fetch the image from somewhere.

Check what exactly you are doing here.

```
com.example.couponapp.adapters.CustomCategoryAdapter.getScaledBitmapFromFile(CustomCategoryAdapter.java:83)
05-24 17:11:36.025: E/AndroidRuntime(708):  at com.example.couponapp.adapters.CustomCategoryAdapter.getView(CustomCategoryAdapter.java:58)
```

In the method getScaledBitmapFromFile, I suspect you are making a network call, which is on the UIThread.

Comment: Thanks!!....@Kumar Bibek. you are right.so I have to download the image in seperate thread.But though I commented out the image download portion,my logcat is still showing "You application may be doin too much work on its main thread".Is it supposed to be shown?I am still a newbie in using asynctask so pardon me if the question is silly...:)

Answer (score 2):

Please, put the code in onPostExecute back to doInBackground and return the result you want to put into your adapter in onPostExecute.

Your problem has to be the JSONArray, see documentation... its not thread-safe ;).

Comment: Like +Kumar Bibek said, getScaledBitmapFromFile(...) can also be the problem. NetworkOnThreadMainException is also called by File-Operations!

Answer (score 0):

If the answer was Luserdroid was not clear then :
You should put your processing code inside the `doInBackground`, I made a mistake of putting processing code inside `onPostExecute` which is executed by main thread and hence I was getting the same issue.